# Microsoft.VisualBasic.Financial.Pmt and amortization in C#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I am trying to calculate amortization schedules and see that the legacy C# code I am updating calls the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Financial.Pmt() method from a VB library. Is it wise to do the same thing for amortization or is there a recommended way to accomplish the same thing in C# without resorting to a VB library call? I am using C# 4.0.

Comment: The Microsoft.VisualBasic library is for backward compatibility with "legacy" VB code, but it it .NET code -- it's not like calling VB6 or unsafe C code.  
I use this lib frequently, especially Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.

Comment: That's not accurate, you are talking about Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.dll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with making a VB.NET library call in C#. That's the recommended way to do this. Unless you find some other .NET financial package.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it myself.  In fact, I have done it myself.  [This](http://www.hughchou.org/calc/formula.html) will give you the formula.

When testing your match, use Excel to check your work, and various online amortization schedules to verify that you are doing it correctly.

It's kind of empowering to calculate this yourself, and also you get some good experience in C# conversion of values when mixing doubles/decimals and ints.

EDIT:  Jim's answer is probably better than mine, but I always like to write something myself (especially as simple as this) as opposed to introducing yet another dependency and being at someone else's mercy with regard to cost/bugs/distribution problems.

I just envision Windows Next coming out with some large change in user rights or access or something ridiculous, and finding out that the dll you are using hasn't (and won't) be updated to take advantage of it.

Comment: That last line has to refer to yours?  Obviously Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll will be kept compatible for a very long time.

Comment: Hans, how can you say that?  .Net broke compatibility with VB Classic.  .Net has breaking changes in its own versions.  There is no guarantee that Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll will be kept compatible with anything, even a service pack.  Yes, it seems unthinkable that it would ever been abandoned.  However, a class file in your own application will never change on you without warning.

Comment: You were talking about *Windows* changing.  Yes, Microsoft has no large commitment to keeping your assembly 100% compatible.  They don't know about it.